# ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in codiegniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have checked the result but unable to solve my error.
I have simply used session_start and it gives this warning message.

> ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's
>   ini settings at this time

Below is my code -

```
$sess_array = array(
                      'id' => $row->empid,
                      'username' => $row->emp_name,
                      'loggedIn' => '1',
                      'usertype' => $usertype
                  );  
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array); // store session
```

Dashboard.php page-

```
session_start();   

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);    

//error_reporting(0);   

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))    

 exit('No direct script access allowed');    




class Dashboard extends CI_Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

}

public function index()
{

    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
        $EmpName = $this->session->userdata['logged_in']['username'];
        $Emp_id = $this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id'];  
  }  
}
```

Although the same question has asked but i didnt get the proper solution for this question. Please anyone solve that query.

Comment: remove `session_start();` from `dashboard.php`. Codeignitor itself started session when project initiated through URL. (through configuration files)

Comment: then it passes the if condition where session is checking and it goes into else part

Comment: There is no `else` part in that code

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention else part. but there is also a else part in this code.

Answer (score 1):

This is really working for me, basically you check for session first then if it is not initialized then you call ini_set and others and then call the session_start()

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {

// server should keep session data for AT LEAST 24 hour
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60 * 60 * 24);

// each client should remember their session id for EXACTLY 24 hour
session_set_cookie_params(60 * 60 * 24);
session_start();
}
```

so you do start your session after calling ini_set and session_set_cookie_params etc

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `session_start();` you should load the session library codeigniter has provided for you in the `application/config/autoload.php` file go the line where:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Or if you want to load the library from only your `Dashboard` controller, you can load it via `$this->load->library('session');`, where you can put it in the constructor to be able to work with it inside the hole controller, or add it in a specific method.

Comment: I have already done this , load session in autoload and when i remove session_start from dashboard.php then if part is not working it goes into else part. Not authenticate session userdata

Comment: $autoload['libraries'] = array( 'database', 'email', 'pagination', 'javascript','encrypt','session');

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the data in the session, try to dump the `$this->session->userdata('logged_in')` after setting it directly.

Comment: Yes, I have dumped it and all values are set properly. I dont know what was the issue, It came first time in my 2 years of development career.

Comment: Try to dump it also in your dashboard controller, and try `has_userdata` in you if statement.

Comment: I have tried in dashboard controller has_userdata it shows that session has no values. although i have set the session  values after successful login. But I have been using session_start() in all my previous project and that time it error has not come.

Comment: yes but if you intend on using CI's session system you cannot use session_start(). I'm not sure where you are doing `$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);` but I would verify before and after using `print_r($_SESSION)` to see where the problem is occurring (e.g. where you are losing session data). we either a) don't have enough info to diagnosis this for you or b) your problem is too localized for anyone to solve in which case start with a fresh CI and XAMPP/localhost copy.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated my session redis driver file: "system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_redis_driver.php" by codeigniter 3.11.1 one:
[new driver file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/3.1.11/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_redis_driver.php)
and this error has disappeared

in application/config/config.php file please put next:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'redis';
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'your-redis-instance:port'
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

it works so far.